# Form with file only uploads filename

Tags: google-app-engine

So basically I'm trying to receive a file and store it in the datastore. Now, I know that you would usually use the blobstore for this, but this is a relatively small (maybe 40-50 kb) text file, so using the blobstore would be overkill.

Problem is, I can't seem to find any way to get the data from the file. The self.request.get("data") and self.request.POST.get("data"), that should contain the file contents (as far as I've understood) is just a string with their filename and no data.

Here is the python 2.7 code:

```
class SubmitHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if not user:
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
        else:
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('templates/submit.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render())

    def post(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if not user:
            self.error(401)
        craft = Craft(submitter = user,
                      title = self.request.get('title'), 
                      description = self.request.get('description'), 
                      data = self.request.get("data"))
        self.redirect('view/' + (hex(craft.put().id()))[2:-1])
```

And the corresponding HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="/submit" method="post">
        <div><textarea name="title" rows="1" cols="40" placeholder="Title"></textarea></div>
        <div><textarea name="description" rows="3" cols="40" placeholder="Description"></textarea></div>
        <div><input type="file" name="data"/></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Upload"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is missing the necessary `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute